# Arabic text and links getting garbled in HTML

Tags: arabic

I am trying to create webpages with Arabic text. I got the pages to finally work on my Mac. When I checked the pages from my Windows 7 PC, this happened:

Image 1 - [image: garbled text]
<sub>(source: [greaturl.com](http://www.greaturl.com/prob1.jpg))</sub>

The text got all garbled. But before that, it was adding a code to my links like %AB%20%XY which I looked up and represents the RTL direction.

But when viewed on my Mac it was fine. But I have thoroughly confused myself reading reams of info on encoding and now am not sure which way is up

Image 2 - [image: file names on server]
<sub>(source: [greaturl.com](http://www.greaturl.com/prob2.jpg))</sub>

The page names were in Arabic and were showing up fine on hosting file manager but then they turned to these garbled file names.

I'm assuming that the hosting server did this or that somehow the server read the file as something other than utf-8

Please help, I have read up and am utterly confused.
Thanks!

Comment: Where's your actual website? In which encoding is it stored? Make sure you have the meta http-equiv element for the character set in your HTML header. If your webserver sends conflicting encoding information, try overriding it in the `.htaccess` (if it's an Apache server).

Comment: first off the second image is supposed to be prob2.jpg (but as being new here I cant edit it) ... and as for htaccess, I heard that it was not a good idea but am not sure as to the downside. Thanks for your tips, I will double check the meta

Answer (score 0):

Add this two lines only

```
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1256" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<meta content="ar-sy" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
</head>
```

[Link](http://code.cside.com/3rdpage/us/windows/windows-1256.html)